# Do row-level binlog entries get recorded in MySQL when a non-null column with a default gets added

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqlbinlog

I wanted to verify the following behavior I noticed with MySQL row-based replication in case there was just something peculiar with our setup or configuration. With row-based replication turned on, and given the following table named **pets**:

```
| id |   name    |    species   |
|----|-----------|--------------|
| 1  |   max     |    canine    |   
| 2  |   spike   |    canine    |
| 3  |   bell    |    feline    |
```

Any updates, deletes, or inserts are recorded in the **binlog**. However, if I were to add a non-null column with a default value, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE `pets` 
ADD COLUMN `sex` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT "unknown" AFTER `species`;
```

The records are updated like so:

```
| id |   name    |    species   |  sex
|----|-----------|--------------|--------
| 1  |   max     |    canine    |  unknown
| 2  |   spike   |    canine    |  unknown
| 3  |   bell    |    feline    |  unknown
```

The behavior I initially expected was that an update would be recorded for each row (since each row undergoes change), and these updates would appear in the **binlog**. However, it actually appears that no row-level events are being written to the **binlog** at all when the new column and default values are added.

Anyways, the questions I have are:

1. Is this behavior expected, or is this indicative of some issue with our setup (or my observational skills)?
2. Is this behavior configurable in any way?

Any information, links, resources, etc will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I would not expect mysql to issue a series of updates statements when replicating this statement, since assigning the default value to a field is definitely not an update of its content. Moreover, your logic is inconsistent because you do not expect a series of updates being generated for fields with null as default value. Null is a value, just like any other default value you pick.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow, yeah, you're right about null being a value too. It still seems like an update to me but I understand your point. At a high-level, it doesn't make sense to me why the new default values wouldn't be reflected in the binlog with row replication turned on (I mean, the row changed in a sense, so that's why I expected to see something in the binlog). Anyways, that could just be my inexperience - but any documentation links for further discussion on why this would be the case is definitely welcome

Comment: Well, found the reference in the documentation, see my answer below.

Comment: @Shadow I commented on your answer below - but I don't think what I'm asking is as illogical as you make it. Either way, I appreciate your input, I can honestly see benefits in both behaviors - which is why I was curious as to whether or not it was configurable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mysql documentation on [binlog format setting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log-setting.html) says (emphasis is mine):

> With the binary log format set to ROW, many changes are written to the binary log using the row-based format. **Some changes, however, still use the statement-based format.** Examples include all DDL (data definition language) statements such as CREATE TABLE, **ALTER TABLE**, or DROP TABLE.

To be honest, your train of thoughts did not seem logical to me, replicating such operations through updates just seemed completely inefficient to me. I know that some complex ddl-dml statements may be partially be replicated through a series of insert / updates, but this does not apply here.

Comment: I understood the initial ALTER table would have been written in statement based format - but different DDL statements have different side-effects on the data itself - so I assumed that the row-based changes would have been reflected in the binlog with __row-based replication__ turned on. I see your point about it being inefficient if the downstream consumer of the binlog is another MySQL instance (MySQL knows how to run the DDL statements, so that's fine), but for other types of downstream systems, the row-level changes may be more useful. Either way, thanks for your answer

Comment: In mysql all default field values are deterministic (constant value or current timestamp), therefore there is not too much point in doing a a full row based replication for these statements.